# How can I  transform/convert my  voice while making a call?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, calls

**Goal:**
Converting a person's voice to another person's voice when you are talking with somebody with the cell in real-time. For instance the sender is a male but his voice will be converted into a female voice.

How can I  transform/convert my  voice while making a call?

Comment: Legato, your question was already closed as off-topic 2 days ago (http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27711/convert-voice-into-another-voice). Please stop to repeat it.

Comment: @Izzy the question was closed because it was a "Is there a App for X?" type, not because of the question topic. It seems to me that the took my advice and rephrased it. Question nominated for reopening.

Comment: That question could be edited and flagged for re-opening. Anyway, voting to re-open.

Comment: boss vt1 is a unit that cost 500 bucks, its the real deal, can change voice as you speak in real time from male to female.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be an app called SpoofApp that let you spoof your caller id and change your voice. It was a free app but you had to buy credits to use it. I tried it and it did work. The voice changer worked too although it sometimes sounded a little cartoonish. The app is now called Phone Gangster and I'm not sure if it still works the same.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to change voice over cellular phone calls, but there's a VoIP calling app which allows you to change voice: [Voice Changer Calling](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.weirdvoice).